# What are the rules for filling community councillor vacancies in Wales?

Tags: united-kingdom, local-government, wales

When a community councillor resigns from a community council in Wales, what are the rules and requirements for filling that vacancy? I know sometimes a by-election is held and sometimes new councillors can be appointed by co-option. Is this at the discretion of council or are there rules in place for when and how it must be filled? As a full local election is currently 5 months away would a community council be allowed to leave the position vacant?

Answer (score 2):

> Community councillors are elected by the local government electors for the community and hold office for a term of 4 years. The chair is elected annually by the council from among the councillors.

**Source:** *[LawWales - Constitution & Goverment - Government in Wales - Communities](http://law.gov.wales/constitution-government/government-in-wales/local-gov/communities/?lang=en#/constitution-government/government-in-wales/local-gov/communities/?tab=overview&lang=en)*

> If a vacancy happens within 6 months of the next election of the full Council, then a Notice of Casual Vacancy has to still be posted but there is no provision for an election to be called.

**Source:** *[City & County of Swansea - Guide to Casual Vacancies](https://democracy.swansea.gov.uk/documents/s19343/Guide%20to%20Casual%20Vacancies.pdf)*

The '6 month rule' given in the document from the website of the City and County of Swansea *(Dinas a Sir Abertawe)* above is drawn from the Local Government Act 1972.

> 89 Filling of casual vacancies in case of councillors.
>
> (1)Subject to the provisions of this section, on a casual vacancy occurring in the office of councillor for any principal area, an election to fill the vacancy shall be held—
>
> (a)in a case in which the High Court or the council have declared the office to be vacant, within [F307thirty-five days] (computed in accordance with section 243(4) below) from the date of the declaration;
>
> (b)in any other case, within [F307thirty-five days] (so computed) after notice in writing of the vacancy has been given to the proper officer of the authority by two local government electors for the area.
>
> (2)The day of election to fill a casual vacancy in any office mentioned in subsection (1) above shall be fixed by the returning officer F308. . .
>
> (3)Where **a casual vacancy in any such office occurs within six months before the day on which the councillor whose office is vacant would regularly have retired**, an election shall not be held under subsection (1) above unless on the occurrence of the vacancy (or in the case of a number of simultaneous vacancies, the occurrence of the vacancies) the total number of unfilled vacancies in the membership of the council exceeds one third of the whole number of members; and where an election under subsection (1) above is not held, the vacancy shall be filled at the next ordinary election.

Emphasis mine.
**Source:** *Local Government Act 1927* ***Could someone add the link, I don't have the rep!***

To answer the other part of your question, the rules and procedures for filling these kinds of vacancies are *largely* drawn from the Local Government Act 1972, however local government is a devolved issue and thus as Welsh Government legislates it can override the LGA1972 as it applies to Wales.

Comment: Link for the last source [Local Government Act 1972](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1972/70)

Comment: Link to devolution settlement for Wales https://www.gov.uk/guidance/devolution-settlement-wales